# custom (css) select option (button) not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I tried to make HTML select dropdown option to button style. it is working perfectly in desktop browsers but it is not working in the mobile browsers.
here the computer view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mphXk.png)

but in mobile view it is showing as a normal select dropdown. the custom CSS not working
here the mobile view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mobmH.jpg)

```css
#id_work_days{
  height: 44px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#id_work_days::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
#id_work_days:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#id_work_days option{
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:rgb(204, 204, 0) solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(204, 204, 0);
}
```

```html
<select name="work_days" id="id_work_days" multiple>
  <option value="1">sun</option>
  <option value="2">mon</option>
  <option value="3">tue</option>
  <option value="4">wed</option>
  <option value="5">thu</option>
  <option value="6">fri</option>
  <option value="7">sat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add some code here

Comment: share the code instead of images and put it in a snippet

Comment: code added. kindly check